# Debug with IDA Pro right click option

Tags: ida, x64dbg

So I was wondering if is there a way for IDA to appears in the righ click options of an executable.

[image]

As you can see, `Debug with x64dbg` was built by itself, IDA 32 didn't do, so I just changed it in the Registry Editor, which it works, but it doesn't show the IDA's icon, also I'm pretty sure this not the right way since I saw some people with this option just like x64dbg is doing it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a text file with content below and save as .REG file. Open .REG file to import into registry. Change the IDA cmd line as appropriate for your system.
For more details refer to Microsoft's documentation on [Context Menus](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\IDA 32]
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\IDA Pro 7.5\\ida.exe\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\IDA 32\Command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\IDA Pro 7.5\\ida.exe\" \"%1\" "

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\IDA 64]
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\IDA Pro 7.5\\ida64.exe\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\IDA 64\Command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\IDA Pro 7.5\\ida64.exe\" \"%1\" "
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!